# Connect perl to SQL Server management 2012

Tags: sql-server, perl

I am new to perl. I am given a task to connect to SQL server management 2012 and print a table from the database. Can you please guide me how to install all the drivers required  and advise me what is wrong with my code, as i get no error and no required output.

```
use DBI;  
my $host     = 'programer';                               #servername  
my $database = 'DW';                                      #database name  
my $user     = 'prg';                                     #username  
my $pwd     = 'prg@123';                                  #password  
my $dsn = "dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$host;Database=$database";  
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pwd) or die("database not found");
$query="select * from Banking_AccountSummary_Citibank";  
$exe=$dbh->prepare($query) or die("cannot prepapre query");  
$exe->execute()or die("cannot execute");  
$dbh->disconnect
```

Please guide me...

Comment: You are not fetching your results. There is nothing wrong. You're just not displaying what you selected. That's why there is no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You don't need to install anything if you have `use strict` and `use warnings` and your code does not issue any warnings and does not `die`.

All you need to do is [fetch your results](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_hashref) and output them, or do whatever you want to do.

```
use Data::Dump;

my $exe = $dbh->prepare("select * from Banking_AccountSummary_Citibank") 
  or die("cannot prepapre query");  
$exe->execute() 
  or die("cannot execute");  

while (my $res = $exe->fetchrow_hashref) {
  dd $res;
}
```

There are several ways to fetch your data and `fetchrow_hashref` is only one of them. I suggest you read the [documentation of DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI) and look at the examples given there.

Note: the convention is to name your statement handles `$sth`, just like the database handle is named `$dbh`. That will help others read your code.

Comment: thank u for response... but when i try printing i get the following error, DBI connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=DW','prg',...) failed: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (SQL-08001) [state was 08001 now 01000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (SQL-01000) at C:/Users/drg/workspace/Test/connectDB.pl line 9.

Comment: So you do get an error. Did you read it? It says the server does not exist or your user credentials are wrong. ;)

Comment: oh sorry it works.... the problem was when i did R&D made a change with $host... it works perfect, thank u :)